# How npmjs.com calculates the code quality

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish

When we publish a package to npm, it will show us some data such as popularity, quality, and maintenance in the search page (The example image is blow). 
I just wonder how npm calculates the quality? Really appreciate if someone can give some clue.

[image]

You can see this if you look on the search page.  See the right side of search page: [npm search for "react"](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react)

Comment: No, it does not show that.  Are you looking at some package's Readme?

Comment: I think you can read it from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-quality#measuring-quality

Comment: If we search some packages, we will see those images in the search list.

Comment: This is flat out, too broad.  You are, in the broadest terms, asking us how to write software to calculate code metrics.  That is, definitively, off-topic according to the reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".

Comment: Hi zero298, I am just asking what kind of criteria the npm is using to calculate the quality.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Edit, january 2020:** NPM does not show *"Powered by npms.io"* anymore. I don't know if this is still accurate.

---

**Original answer**

[**npm**](https://www.npmjs.com) shows these graphs in search results, but they do not calculate these values themselves. If you look below the search results, you'll see "Powered by [**npms.io**](https://npms.io)".

According to this service, they don't inspect the code, but use the following metrics to measure code quality:

- Has README? Has license? Has `.gitignore` and friends?
- Is the version stable (`> 1.x.x`)? Is it deprecated?
- Has tests? What's their coverage %? Is the build passing?
- Has outdated dependencies? Do they have vulnerabilities?
- Has custom website? Has badges?
- Are there linters configured?

*Source: https://npms.io/about*

Comment: Thank you. It is what I am looking for. I should look at that page more carefully. You have a nice day.

Comment: When checking npm.io, this code might be of help to understand npm's package quality evaluation: https://github.com/npms-io/npms-analyzer/blob/master/lib/scoring/score.js

Comment: Currently, the numbers are different (which is a pity). My quality score of https://npms.io/search?q=%40mliebelt%2Fpgn-parser is 83 (quality) and 100 (maintenance), but on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pgn-parser), the score is 53 and 33. I think the values are old, and not computed any more at all.

Comment: See the discussion here https://github.com/npm/feedback/discussions/66 to understand the current state. So npms.io is not used any more, and the metrics are not open / not clearly defined.

Answer (score 3):

> Quality includes considerations such as the presence of a README file, stability, tests, up-to-date dependencies, custom website, and code complexity.

https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download