# My node package's quality score went from 99% to 65% on an update

Tags: javascript, npm, ranking

The goal of the update was to add the `files` property to the `package.json` to lead to a smaller download.  Nothing else but the readme changed.

Code coverage is still 100%.  Issues are closed.  There are no outstanding PRs.

I used to have the second or third spot on NPM for all my relevant search terms.  Now I'm not on the front page.

When I look at `npms.io`, the score is for a version from two months ago.  I don't know how to get it updated.  That version is quality 99.99%

How do I diagnose what is downgrading my quality score?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jssm

---

Edit: oh, wow.  I removed the `files` section and the quality went back up to 95.

Either the presence of a files section broke it, or the quality is somehow dependent on a file I was excluding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How npmjs.com calculates the code quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866588/how-npmjs-com-calculates-the-code-quality)

Comment: No, it does not.  NPMjs hasn't used npms.io for a long time, and as I said, I did check it already; it's a month out of date