# How scores are calculated in npmjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

There is already a related question in [How npmjs.com calculates the code quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866588/how-npmjs-com-calculates-the-code-quality/49867121#49867121).

But it looks like [npms.io](https://github.com/npms-io) hasn't been maintained in a while, and after some research, it is still unclear to me how the code quality in npm packages is calculated.